# Form handling action understanding

Tags: php

This code works perfectly but if I my form in different page it does not work

```
$name = isset($_REQUEST["name"]) ? $_REQUEST["name"] : ""; // Andrew

$phoneBook = array("Andrew" => 2753, "Colin" => 2863, "Ken" => 2782);

foreach($phoneBook as $k => $v)
{
if( $k == $name ){
    echo $k. " ".$v; // Andrew 2753
}
}
?>

<form action = "kds.php" method ="GET">
name : <input type = "text" name = "name"/>
<input type = "submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: The different page has the exact same code?

Comment: sorry what do you mean

Comment: The code in this question is the same code used on 2 pages and on one of those pages it doesn't function the same? Is that correct?

Comment: yeah correct but its works  perfectly when we use in same page

Comment: Can you explain on the scenario a bit more where it doesnt work?

Comment: forms  works perfectly on same page where if i use different page and in action i put name of the file it does print the data

Comment: I'm not following you. When does it not work?

Comment: try on your computer please

Comment: Sorry, I can't help if you cant describe the issue. It sounds like what you are thinking is happening isn't happening.

Answer (score 1):

You have the action relative to the current page. So if you are in `www.mysite.com` the action is `www.mysite.com/kds.php`, but if you are in `www.mysite.com/page` the action will be `www.mysite.com/page/kds.php`. Yoy can set the action relative to the root setting like this `<form action = "/kds.php" method ="GET">`

Comment: <form action = "/Newfile.php" method ="GET">
name : <input type = "text" name = "name"/>
<input type = "submit"/>
</form>  it does not work

Comment: Is `Newfile.php` under the root path?

Comment: new file is where this code exist                                                            $name = isset($_REQUEST["name"]) ? $_REQUEST["name"] : ""; // Andrew

$phoneBook = array("Andrew" => 2753, "Colin" => 2863, "Ken" => 2782);

foreach($phoneBook as $k => $v)
{
if( $k == $name ){
    echo $k. " ".$v; // Andrew 2753
}
}
?>code exit

Comment: The question is, what is the url to `Newfile.php`?